# FFMPEG convert from .mov to .webm - "Unable to find suitable output for vp8"

Tags: unity-game-engine, ffmpeg, webm

I need a transparent video for unity and the only solution I found is with a .webm.

a couple of moths ago I used this:

> ffmpeg -i input.mov -c:v libvpx -minrate 10M -maxrate 10M -b:v 10M -c:a  -vcodec vp8 -pix_fmt yuva420p -metadata:s:v:0 alpha_mode="1" output.webm

but now it give me this error:

> Unable to find suitable output for vp8
>
> Vp8 invalid argument

I don't know ffmpeg so I can't change the command.
Are there errors or I miss some codec?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`-c:a -vcodec vp8` The first option (audio codec) is missing its value so ffmpeg is setting `-vcodec` as the value, which leaves `vp8` unpaired and thus treated as an output filename. Since there is no extension in this "filename", ffmpeg can't set an output format.

Remove the entire set: `-c:a -vcodec vp8`. `-c:v libvpx` upfront already sets the VP8 encoder.